# What to do? Apple rejected my app for reasons that are untrue

Tags: macos, submission

Apple's reasons for rejecting my app are not true.

They claim: 
*We found that when Dark Mode is enabled, the menu texts in app aren't visible.*

They included screen shots of windows (not menus) with white text, but when I run the app I submitted in dark mode, it shows these windows (and the menu bar menus and the submenus) in black in high contrast with their background.

I responded with a comment to that effect with screen shots.  What's going on?  Am I trying to talk to a bot?  Would I be better off removing the app and resubmitting the same app along with a complaining comment?

I can't afford to wait for some unspecified time until I get an answer, especially since I have no confidence they will even respond with an answer.

I am so upset, I'm worried about my health.  I'm 73 with a history of heart issues.  This is hugely important to me.  I don't think Apple gives a ****.  If I die with a heart attack, with this on the record at lease my heirs can sue Apple.

Comment: You can either respond, as you did, showing what you believe to be correct and hopefully asking for more details or context, or you can submit again and hope you get a different reviewer or result. There's no reason to complain if you submit again because doing so just calls extra attention to the fact that you failed the last review. Yes, sometimes their rejections make no sense, but sometimes they are using a different hardware/operating system combination and the problem is real.

Comment: How about when you toggle dark mode while the app is running?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the dark mode easily, Find the info.plist,

```
UIUserInterfaceStyle = Light
```

Comment: Thanks Jim.  I'll give them until Monday morning, then go your route if I don't get a responsive reply.